# How can I append the name of a file to end of each line in that file?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I need to do the following for hundreds of files:
Append the name of the file (which may contain spaces) to the end of each line in the file.

It seems to me there should be some way to do this:

```
sed -e 's/$/FILENAME/' *
```

where `FILENAME` represents the name of the current file.  Is there a sed variable representing the current filename?  Or does anyone have a different solution using bash, awk, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, I'd use perl:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/$/$ARGV/;' *
```

Comment: Nice!  Though it only worked if I separated the options and did perl -pi -e instead of perl -pie.

Comment: -pie won't work, because -i takes an optional argument. -pei or -epi should work OTOH.

Comment: @LeonTimmermans, `-pei` and `-epi` won't work because `-e` also expects an argument. You can't really bundle `-i` and `-e` into the same group.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a bash script

```
for i in * 
do
  sed -e "s/\$/$i/" "$i" 
done
```

One-liner version:

```
for i in * ; do sed -e "s/\$/$i/" "$i" ; done
```

**Edit:** If you want to *replace* the contents of the file with the new, name-appended lines, do this:

```
TFILE=`mktemp`
for i in * 
do
  sed -e "s/\$/$i/" "$i" > $TFILE
  cp -f $TFILE "$i"
done
rm -f $TFILE
```

Comment: You need quotes around all filename variables for this to work with files that contains spaces as the OP required.

Comment: For things like this, rather than using mktemp, I'll use "TFILE=tmp.$$".  "$$" is the PID, so it's going to be unique.  Just a stylistic difference.

Answer (score 4):

Some versions of sed support the "--in-place" argument so you can condense Tyler's solution to

```
for i in * ; do 
  sed -e "s/\$/$i/" --in-place "$i" 
done
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm not a sed expert as you can see. :)

However you do need a linebreak (or a semi-colon) between the * and the do.

Comment: And of course when I typed it into a bash shell to test it, I had the semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' > tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In BASH, I'd do something to the effect of:

```
for f in *; do echo $f >> $f; done
```

Comment: That will append the name of the file to the end of the file, but not to the end of each line.

Comment: i think that only adds the filename to the end of the file, not each line?

Answer (score 0):

More or less how Tyler suggested, just with some modifications to allow for spaces in the name.  I was hoping for a one-liner though...

```
(
  OLDIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for f in *
  do
    IFS=OLDIFS
    sed -e "s/\$/$f/" $f > tmpfile
    mv tmpfile $f
    IFS=$'\n'
  done
)
```

Comment: If you're willing to use perl, my answer above hits it in 25 characters.

Comment: Don't mess with IFS: use "$f" (in double quotes) for each reference.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
printf "%s\n" * | sed 's/.*/sed -i "s|$| &|" &/' | bash
```